# Concerning left nullspace

Tags: linear-algebra

There's a question that makes me reduce a matrix A to echelon form, which has a row of zeros. Then knowing the combinations of the rows which make the zero row in the echelon form of A, we can work out the vector(s) in the null space.

My question is why does this work? As in we know row3 - 2row2 + row1 gives a zero row in the echelon form of A. but why does this mean the null space contains the vector (1, -2, 1) which are the coefficients of the above row combination?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the intermediate steps while going from the first matrix to the second one. The original matrix us$$\left[\begin{array}{rrr|l}1&2&3&b_1\\4&5&6&b_2\\7&8&9&b_3\end{array}\right].\tag1$$Then you add the first line times $-4$ to the second one and you add the first line times $-7$ to the third one, getting$$\left[\begin{array}{rrr|l}1&2&3&b_1\\0&-3&-6&b_2-4b_1\\0&-6&-12&b_3-7b_1\end{array}\right].$$Then you add the seconf line times $-2$ to the third line and you get$$\left[\begin{array}{rrr|l}1&2&3&b_1\\0&-3&-6&b_2-4b_1\\0&0&0&b_1-2b_2+b_3\end{array}\right].$$That $b_1-2b_2+b_3$ at the lower right corner tells you how the bottom line was obtained from the lines of $(1)$: it's the first line minus twice the second line plus the third line. But then, in particular,$$(0,0,0)=(1,2,3)-2(4,5,6)+(7,8,9).$$

Comment: Ahhh I understood what the linear combination at the lower right corner was telling me but I failed to acknowledge that the b's represent rows - I kept thinking the b's were single variables for some reason. Thank you for making it super clear for me!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.